# Python - HDF5 to numpy array - out of memory

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have a HDF5 file that contains 20'000'000 rows, each row has 8 float32 columns. The total raw memory size should be approx 640MB.

I want to load this data in my Python app, however, during the load to numpy array I run out of memory (I have 64GB RAM)

I use this code:

```
import h5py

hf = h5py.File(dataFileName, 'r')
data = hf['data'][:]
```

For smaller files it works ok, however, my input is not so big as well. So is there any other way how to load the entire dataset to memory because it should fit without any problems.
On the other hand, why it takes so much memory? Even if it would internally convert float32 to float64 it is not nearly the size of the entire RAM.

Dataset info from HDFView 3.3.0

[image]

Comment: Does the error occur during *h5py.File()* or when you try to copy *hf['data']*?

Comment: What is the actual error message? Please include it verbatim in the question.

Comment: There is no error message... I can see memory spiking until it goes out of memory and program crashes. The problem is during copy from hf['data'], open is OK. I can open the file in HDF5Viewer without any problem as well.

Comment: Are you sure about the data size? Print `hf['data'].shape` and `hf['data'].dtype` to double check

Comment: Current dataset is even smaller `shape: (16409916, 8)` and `dtype: float32`

Comment: This makes no sense to me, I have loaded large HDF5 files like this and it works fine, so it is likely a detail that is not in the question.

Comment: There is no other code... isn't it possible that HDF5 file is incorrectly saved?

Comment: There is always other code, like the code that generated the file, I think this will end  up closed as not reproducible.

Comment: I don't have the code that generated the file. I have added dataset info from HDFView

Comment: Are you getting a memory error with a traceback, or do you _**think you have a memory error**_ because the process locks up? I suspect the 2nd. Why? A chunk shape of `(2,8)` is terrible and I/O will be incredibly slow. When I modified my example to demonstrate, it locked up my system. Once I restore, I will modify my answer so you can test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sign of trouble could have been that the file, while holding some 500 MiB of data, actually has a size of about 850 MiB; at least when I replicate it on my system. This indicates an excessive amount of overhead.

The tiny chunk size combined with the rather large data set size apparently breaks the HDF5 library or at least gets it to allocate an enormous amount of memory. As a test, this will consume all memory and swap on my system if I don't kill the process fast enough:

```py
data = np.random.random((16409916, 8)).astype('f4')
with h5py.File(outpath, "w") as outfile:
    dset = outfile.create_dataset("data", data=data, chunks=(2, 8))
```

Meanwhile this will work but is very slow:

```py
with h5py.File(outpath, "w") as outfile:
    dset = outfile.create_dataset(
            "data", shape=data.shape, dtype=data.dtype, chunks=(2, 8))
    for start in range(0, len(data), 2):
        end = start + 2
        dset[start:end] = data[start:end]
```

Likewise, you cannot read it all at once with such a ludicrous chunk size. If I had to guess why, the library probably wants to figure out all chunk locations before reading them. This turns a rather compact on-disk representation into a large one in memory.

Try something like this as a workaround:

```py
with h5py.File(inpath, "r") as infile:
    dset = infile["data"]
    shape, dtype = dset.shape, dset.dtype
    data = np.empty(shape, dtype)
    raw_chunksize = 1024**2 # 1 MiB
    raw_rowsize = dtype.itemsize * np.prod(shape[1:])
    chunksize = max(1, raw_chunksize // raw_rowsize)
    for start in range(0, len(data), chunksize):
        end = start + chunksize
        data[start:end] = dset[start:end]
```

Please tell whoever created those files to read up on the meaning of chunk size and choose one appropriately; typically in the range of 64 kiB to 1 MiB.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. If you are only loading a single 640MB dataset to a single NumPy array on a system with 64 GB RAM, you should not run out of memory. If you are, likely the problem is somewhere else. Are you loading a lot of arrays simultaneously? Does you program have other objects that require a lot of memory? Are there other applications running that also consume a lot of memory?

Start by diagnosing behavior with a simple test case. I wrote a program to create a HDF5 file with 1 dataset, closes the file and then opens and reads it into 1 array. This runs on my system with 24 GB RAM, and should run on your system. (Code at end.) If it works for you, that confirms you can read this size array and the problem is somewhere else in your program. If it doesn't run, there is a bigger problem with HDF5/h5py usage on your system.

Note: you can also reduce memory usage by creating dataset objects. These "behave like" NumPy arrays, but have a much smaller memory footprint. This also is demonstrated in the code.

**Code below:**

```
a0, a1 = 20_000_000, 8
arr = np.random.random(a0*a1).reshape(a0,a1).astype(np.float32)
with h5py.File('SO_76906733.h5','w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset('test',data=arr)
    
with h5py.File('SO_76906733.h5','r') as h5f:
    print(h5f['test'].dtype, h5f['test'].shape)
    dset = h5f['test']  ## creates h5py dataset object
    print(f'Dataset memory used: {sys.getsizeof(dset)}')
    data = h5f['test'][()]  ## creates numpy array object
    print(f'Array memory used: {sys.getsizeof(data)}')
```

Comment: I have added breakpoints and I hit `h5py.File` and during the next step `hf['data'][:]` I can see memory consumption rising until the program crashes.

Comment: When I run your code, I dont have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get "someone" to recreate the file for you, you can do it yourself. Code below uses the same approach @Homer512 suggested to copy the data. It creates a new file and dataset with `chunks=(30_000,8)`. This will give much better I/O performance. Read time for the dataset in the new file is less than a second.

The timing and print statements in my code aren't necessary. I included them to get some feedback while running. Note that the row read factor of 36 rows works for this data set and avoids an incremental read on the last loop. You will have to adjust it for the more general case.

Code below:

```
start = time.time()
row_fact = 36
with h5py.File('smallchunks.h5','r') as h5r, \
     h5py.File('largechunks.h5','w') as h5w:
    dset = h5r['test']
    data = np.empty(dset.shape, dset.dtype)
    # first, read dataset into an array
    for i in range(dset.shape[0]//row_fact):
        data[i*36:i*row_fact+row_fact] = dset[i*row_fact:i*row_fact+row_fact]
        if not (i % 50_000):
            print(f'time to read to row {i*row_fact+row_fact:,}: {time.time()-start:.2f}')    

    print(f'time to read small chunked file: {time.time()-start:.2f}\n')    

    start = time.time()
    h5w.create_dataset('test', data=data, maxshape=(None,8), chunks=(30_000,8))
    print(f'time to create large chunked file: {time.time()-start:.2f}\n')

start = time.time()   
with h5py.File('largechunks.h5','r') as h5f:
    data = h5f['test'][()]
print(f'time to read large chunked file: {time.time()-start:.2f}')
```